# Can I setup multiple sites under one Craft install?

Tags: multi-site

I have not used Craft much, but can I setup multiple sites under one Craft install?

If I can, which version of Craft is needed?

Thanks.

Comment: I mean multiple sites not languages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you definitely can, both in Craft 2 and Craft 3. I would recommend using Craft 3 (3.1 beta if you can) so you use the latest improvements available.

On Craft 3 you can set different Groups for different pages and then different sites within each group for the different languages.

I recommend [this video](https://mijingo.com/lessons/craft-3-multi-site/), it helps a lot with the set-up and understanding how it works.

Anyway, I am not sure if you might need different license type for setting more than one site on production.